# Disable a button when textbox has data in it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I see so many people ask to disable a button when a textbox is empty . how about disable a button when a textbox has data ?

this is my button code

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reserve" />
```

this is my textbox code

```
Name : <br><br><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"     <?php if($name != "") echo "readonly"?> /> <br><br>

Name : <br><br><input type="text" name="name2" value="<?php echo $name2;?>" <?php if($name2 != "") echo "readonly"?> /> <br><br>
```

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reserve" />

Comment: Please clarify your question what you ask?

Comment: i want to disable a button when a textbox has a data . this is my textbox code example . 

Name : <br><br><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" <?php if($name != "") echo "readonly"?> /> <br><br>

this is my button code 

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reserve" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reserve" <?php echo ($name != "")?"disabled":""; ?>/>
```

**Using jQuery**

```
$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup',function(){   
    disable_button();
});

function disable_button()
{
    flag = false;
    $(":input").each(function(){
       if($(this).val()==""){
          flag=true;
       }
   });
   if(flag){
      $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled",false);
   }
   else
   {
     $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled",true);
  } 
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zzwss6nn/1/)

Comment: how about when i have 2 textbox ? here is the code . 
    Name : <br><br><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" <?php if($name != "") echo "readonly"?> /> <br><br>

  Name : <br><br><input type="text" name="name2" value="<?php echo $name2;?>" <?php if($name2 != "") echo "readonly"?> /> <br><br>

Comment: Do you want button `disabled` when any of `textbox` is empty? Am I right?

Comment: i think you misunderstanding . i want to disabled button when textbox has data in it

Comment: If one textbox is `empty` and `second` is `filled` then what you want?

Comment: yes . i want to make it enabled when one textbox is empty and disabled when both textbox is filled

Comment: just now i see you edited your code . but my second textbox named name2 . how to make it ?

Comment: okay . i'll wait for it . sorry for too many question . i'm new in making a system .

Comment: but the button enable when the textbox is filled . i want the button disable when the textbox is filledd .